# Same Content for Multiple ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to show the same `ComboBoxItem`s in multiple `ComboBox`es.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="5" />
</ComboBox>
```

Is there an easy way to do this without repeating the code and only in XAML (not using code-behind)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer you question yes, you can create a common array in the Xaml and assign it to the ItemsSource of your ComboBox's. It would look something like this. This can be put in your application resources for program wide visibility.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Window.Resources>
       <x:ArrayExtension x:Key="myArray" Type="system:String">
           <system:String>1</system:String>
           <system:String>2</system:String>
           <system:String>3</system:String>
           <system:String>4</system:String>
           <system:String>5</system:String>
       </x:ArrayExtension>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{StaticResource myArray}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
       <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{StaticResource myArray}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,10,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple - Databind the Comboboxes to the same DataSource.

---

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding CommonItems} />
```

This will search in the DataContext of the Window/UserControl that the ComboBox is a child of for a public property called CommonItems and use it as an ItemSource.

---

Quick sample:

If you have a simple window in a WPF application, in the Window code behind you can set in the constructor:

```
Window1()
{
  this.DataContext = this;
}
```

after that, define a public property CommonItems in which you can set the list that you want to use in multiple ItemsControls:

```
 public List<string> CommonItems {get;set;}
```

and in the Window UI code (the xaml file) you can use the CommonItems list as a ItemSource for multiple controls and it will work.

Comment: If you don't know how to use DataBinding and what's the deal with DataContexts you should read up on some tutorials because a quick sample from me or someone else will not be of help to you because you will not understand why it works. Happy Coding!

Comment: Either with code behind or with code in the ViewModel attached, you will have to provide that collection somewhere common so that all the comboboxes can access it. There is another way, you can define the list of items in a resource dictionary or directly in the window.resources where the comboboxes are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var priceList = new List<int>
                        {
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            5
                        };

    //Now we can use CopyTo() Method

    priceList.CopyTo(insuredList);


    ComboBox1.Datasource=priceList;
    ComboBox2.Datasource=insuredList;
```

//Without code behind methods:

You need to create new ComboBoxItems for each ComboBox. Usually you would use one source   collection and [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) it to both ComboBoxes, they then will create the new items on their own.

You can also use [application resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624.aspx). Adding your own style(template) to global resource allow you share it with multiple controls.